# Hide order status in order page woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Helllo,

I want to hide cancel order status for particular orders in order details page admin side.

I want to hide from all order status list drop-down in order page.

Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove status " Cancelled" from order status list.

```
add_action('wc_order_statuses', 'my_statuses');

function my_statuses($order_statuses) {

    unset($order_statuses['wc-cancelled']);
    return $order_statuses;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine.